# MySQL PHP Order by Random for a certain time?

Tags: php, mysql, random, time

For example, say if you wanted a random result every 10 minutes. Is there a way to achieve this with `ORDER BY RAND()`?

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "
  SELECT * 
    FROM food 
    JOIN food_images ON food.size = food_images.size 
    ORDER BY RAND()
");
```

I also am using a `JOIN` and worried if this might affect the answers. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean, you want the same random result every time you query for the next 10 minutes, then you want a different random result for the next 10 minutes, and so on?

Comment: @AlexHowansky That's correct. If it's possible.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `ORDER BY RAND()` doesn't always work the way you'd expect as MySQL (perhaps some versions) optimize the RAND() reference to a single call, rather than a call per result row. You can instead do something like `SELECT *, RAND() AS seq .... ORDER BY seq` to insure different rand results though. However, repeating these kinds of queries can get expensive if the overall results are large; you might want to consider selecting a list of identifying values once at startup, and having the code that executes the query pick the identifier randomly for a more targeted query.

Comment: If you dont want same results each time you can make additional table where you put data on each rand and use it in way to pick rand from all besides same as in the table.

Comment: @StupidKid I want the same results for 10 minutes, then after those 10 minutes are up, make a new result.

Comment: You could use a cache like `memcached` to save the results, with a time-to-live of 10 minutes.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams when you fetch result add it to aalready_fetched table, next time on fetchin check is that result in fetched table or not if not add it to that table or fetch another

Comment: @StupidKid I don't really feel like it should be all that work. Or at least to me it seems like I'd be going through too much to be doing that. Barmar, I'll have to looking into that, but thank you

Comment: well you need to store somewhere values that has been picked already since rand may pick em again... thats how i do it when i send emails with rand examples. i dont want same examples every time so i need to store already picked ones somewhere and place it back. i am doing it in laravel so i wont share it here since its not vanilla php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a MySQL server in front of me so most of this is a guess, but you might try as follows:

You can generate a number that changes only once every ten minutes by taking the system time in seconds, dividing by the number of seconds in ten minutes, and then casting to an integer:

```
$seed = (int) (time() / 600);
```

Then pass this value to MySQL's `RAND()` function as a parameter to seed the RNG, and you should get a repeatable sequence that changes every ten minutes:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND(?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $seed);
```

Comment: You may want to benchmark that query, if you have large tables it may be costly and you may want to switch to one of the other variants noted. The effect of the seed should still apply in the same manner.

Comment: What could happen if I do this which say like a thousand or more rows? Will it be slower or what is likely to happen?

Comment: I don't think so. The effort to produce random numbers is negligible compared to fetch rows, or walk an index.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND` generally destroys any use of indexing your database might normally do. If it's a simple query on a small table, it won't matter much. You'll have to test to find out.

Comment: `:seed` is a PDO placeholder and the OP/you used mysqli_. That won't work. Edit: This, as per original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51866461/1

Comment: Oops, thanks, fixed. I never use the non-PDO versions.

Comment: @AlexHowansky welcome; gotta ping me just in case ;-) I could've been swooped away by Lord knows what *lol!*

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
SELECT *, rand(time_to_sec(current_time()) / 600) as ord
  FROM food 
  JOIN food_images ON food.size = food_images.size 
  order by ord
```

The parameter of the `RAND()` function is the seed. The expression in it, changes only every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, but where does the time come in? Will this have a different result after 10 minutes? I am just wondering...

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your question. Unless there's a way to add a seed, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It's fine, I appreciate your answer +1

Comment: Actually, I think there is.

Comment: Yes! This also works! Thank you so much! @TheImpaler

Comment: Ah dang, I forgot that MySQL had that function to easily get the epoch time! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) and as described in the documentation:

> you are creating a named database object containing one or more SQL statements to be executed at one or more regular intervals, beginning and ending at a specific date and time

And I guess you are using php so You can use PHP Cron jobs too , [Managing Cron Jobs With PHP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjT9Net_u_cAhWGPFAKHQuzBC8QFjACegQIBhAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fmanaging-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428&usg=AOvVaw0vSvfHfME0flh1D94Ci2jB)

Comment: He doesn't want to run the query every 10 minutes, he wants to run it whenever he needs it, but have the results stay the same for that 10-minute period.